# Can I organize Doctrine YAML mappings in subfolders?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, yaml, symfony

I have custom mapping settings in my Symfony3 project for Doctrine entities like this:

```
MyModel:
    type: yml
    dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/MyModel
    prefix: MyProject\MyModel\Model
    is_bundle: false
```

Let's assume I have an entity `MyProject\MyModel\Model\SubNamespace\MyEntity`. Now, I have to put its yml mapping in `%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/MyModel/SubNamespace.MyEntity.orm.yml`, and it works fine.

Can I configure Doctrine to be able to organize mapping files in subfolders instead of file names being a concatenation of parts of namespace after prefix?

In this case if would be `%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/MyModel/SubNamespace/MyEntity.orm.yml`

The reason is that mapping directory is growing and it's getting hard to find any particular file inside.

Of course, it's not a solution to make a configuration for every subfolder. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/SymfonyFileLocator.php), there's nothing to handle subfolders. But then the trick could be to add each folder in a different "mapping", as far I know those don't have to stick to your Symfony bundles:

```
doctrine:
    # ...
    orm:
        # ...
        mappings:
            AcmeBundleFoo:
                type: yml
                dir: AcmeBundle/Resources/doctrine/Foo
            AcmeBundleBar:
                type: yml
                is_prefix: false # you are free to let Symfony guess it or to be explicit
                dir: AcmeBundle/Resources/doctrine/Bar
```

A little verbose, but it should work given yout folder structure is src/AcmeBundle/Resources indeed.

Comment: Thank you for looking into the source for me. ;-) I was not sure where to look. And yes, I know I can add config for every subfolder, but as I mentioned in last sentence of my question, that won'y work for me.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's in conf files :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        #etc

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: false //default was true
        mappings:
            MySuperBundleName:
                type: yml
                dir: Resources/somewhereElse/doctrine // your specific directory
```

Comment: `auto_mapping` let's me **change** the directory, but it seems it doesn't make Doctrine look into both `(...)/doctrine/MyModel` **and** all its subfolders **like**  `(...)/doctrine/MyModel/SubNamespace`